# What happened to Okoye's car?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther-2018

While involved in a chase, Okoye's car was disabled and she had to abandon it.

Considering that

> The car was made of Vibranium

It seems likely that she'd want to recover it. But between the low amount of Wakandan personnel involved, the presence of foreign observers, the thoroughly disabled state of the vehicle, and the medical emergency, the logistics of a recovery seem difficult if not impossible.

Is the final fate of the car ever clarified?

Comment: Was it Okoye’s car? T’Challa slapped one of Shuri’s remote control devices on it. It looked like it was just the first car they came across.

Comment: T'Challa and Shuri carjacked a random passerby, but Okoye and Nakia were in a Wakandan-made vehicle, as evidenced by the spoilery bit that came up when Klaue's minions shot at them.

Comment: As far as as I remember, nothing more was shown of the car

Comment: Well, this makes a point ( Spoliers)  - http://textsfromsuperheroes.com/image/171329085342 - so it's something that SHIELD would have to deal with.

Comment: It ended up in a museum mislabelled as a Ford Pinto.